# Vocabulary - How to name a potential visitor viewing your link in a SERP?

Tags: seo

When someone performs a search on a search engine and is presented a result page, he is a click away of becoming a visitor of one of the listed links. If you own site appears in the list, you could consider this person as a "potential visitor".

However, "potential visitor" sounds a bit unclear. For example, this term could be used to designate someone who might be interested in the site at a later time, but this is not what we mean here. Is there a more specific term to name this person?

Answer (score 2):

For me this is a visitor, who makes a **SERP impression**. Such visitors are listed in GSC (not by name, I'm afraid, but by impressions amount your certain URL earned). This lets us pretty clearly describe such users.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and thank you @Stephen-Ostermiller for the edition. So how would you call the person? "User doing a SERP impression"?